# Problema VSCode acrescentando espaço no código

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Olá, pessoal.

Ao trabalhar com HTML toda vez que é feita uma alteração no *head* automaticamente o VSCode acrescenta um espaço antes de fechar todas as aspas duplas no *body*. Ficando como neste exemplo: *input type="checkbox " id="ps4 " name="ps4 " value="ps4 "*

Essa situação acaba desconfigurando a apresentação do site no navegador (Firefox, no caso). Pra resolver, eu tenho que ir tirando os espaços, um por um. Por que isso acontece? E qual seria a melhor maneira de resolver?

Grata.

Comment: Provavelmente vc instalou alguma extensão de formatação de código, vc pode desabilita-la ou ler na documentação dela se existe alguma config sobre isso

Answer (score 0):

Opa, você pode está fazendo da seguinte forma, no `settings.json` do vscode, você coloca essas configurações:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
```

Provavelmente vai está resolvendo seu problema, abraços!

Answer (score -1):

Mo meu caso desinstalei a extensão: "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter"
Podes desativa-lo, caso não estas a utilizar.